# Authlogic, multiple user types and multiple relations between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, relationship

Good morning,

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage this user situation I've got.

I have users and affiliates.  There is already a HABTM relationship between the two of them, because users can sign up for affiliates, and affiliates can reach out and touch users, in order to get various data points.

Now I need to set up a new Authlogic user type, let's call them affiliate managers, to *manage* affiliates.  Each affiliate manager can only manage one affiliate, and they should not be counted in the affiliate's user count.

Our app is already using Authlogic to separate regular users and admins, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around how I would build in this latest piece: specifically the relationship between the affiliate and the manager.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to solve this with single table inheritance. Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance